# What is so special about interactions in regression?

Tags: regression, interaction

I was recently asked why I haven't analysed interactions in my (predictive) regression model (I understood "*interactions*" here to mean products of predictor variables). The easy answer is that I had no reason to suspect interactions. But, more deeply, I wonder why interactions are so special? They are simply non-linear transformations of the original data. Why does it make more sense to use interactions, and not any other non-linear transformation (power, logarithm plus cosine etc.)?

On the other hand, every statistical software I know offers a way to specify interactions in the model, so, obviously, they are considered important among statisticians. Why?

Comment: Much has been written about this here on CV: please search our site for [highly voted answers about regression interaction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interaction+regression+is%3Aanswer+score%3A10).

Comment: in intuitive terms: it's because things tend to interact with each other in the real world. The impact of changing variable $X_1$ on $Y$ often is modulated by the setting of some other variable $X_2$. Actually, it's probably even worse than this: there are probably many interactions of various orders between many variables. But the combinatorics make it difficult in practice to consider higher order interactions, so we often stop at order 2. We shouldn't make the mistake of thinking that statistics is a subdiscipline of mathematics: here the answer comes from the way the real world is.